# How to traverse in the database table using parent id?

Tags: mysql, sql, traversal

We have the MYSQL table that contains ID, PARENT_ID and contract terms:

```
CONTRACTTERM

+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+
| ID              | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| PARENT_ID       | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| FROM_DATE       | date        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| TO_DATE         | date        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
```

To find FROM_DATE and TO_DATE one needs to traverse using parent_id until parent_id is NULL.  Then the last parent FROM_DATE and TO_DATE show contract terms.  Is it possible to find these dates using SQL?

One of the option is to use the following SQL, but it works only if we know the number of iterations:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t4.FROM_DATE, t4.TO_DATE FROM CONTRACTTERM t1, CONTRACTTERM t2, 
CONTRACTTERM t3, CONTRACTTERM t4  WHERE t1.ID in (27533, 57665, 58057) 
and t2.ID=t1.PARENT_ID  
and t3.ID=t2.PARENT_ID  
and t4.ID=t3.PARENT_ID 
and t4.PARENT_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY t4.TO_DATE DESC;
```

Comment: can you provide a little more information on the following  1) what is this database SQL Server, MY SQL or Oracle or ?? 2) should the from_date and to_date be from the parent_id after traversal or from_date from parent_id where it is null and the to_date from the ID that you are looking for??

Comment: Thank you, added the info you asked

Comment: how about some sample data with the expected output?

Comment: So if you are looking at parent_id = k, you only want to return the data for k if parent_id = k+1 doesn't exist (aka is null)? I guess I am confused about how the data is sorted. Is it incrementally by id? What counts as "the last parent"?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get these dates by using LIMIT and ORDER BY. If you are looking for the most current contract dates for a specific PARENT_ID, try something like:

> SELECT * FROM CONTRACTTERM WHERE PARENT_ID = (:parent_id) ORDER BY
>   TO_DATE DESC LIMIT 1

If you are trying to get the most current dates for any contract with a non-null PARENT_ID, try:

> SELECT * FROM CONTRACTTERM WHERE PARENT_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY
>   TO_DATE DESC LIMIT 1

ps: I found this info at
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx
and
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/is_not_null.php

Comment: I tried - it is not working, thanks. In any case select TOP is specific for MS SQL Server

Comment: @anarinsky - Crap. You're right. MySQL uses LIMIT instead. I have edited my answer accordingly.